# How to get a list of all Latin based alphabet characters but exclude 'special characters' in PHP

Tags: php, character

I am working on a PHP based system that is planned to be rolled out around Europe and for a certain form field I am trying to limit input to just alphabetical characters only.

However, this could take the guise of the English language alphabet - but also the German, Latvian, Polish, French, Spanish, etc alphabets.

I am looking at ISO-8859-1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table), which seems to be quite complete as far as the alphabet goes. But I see no easy way to tell between alphabet characters and what I know in English as 'special characters'.

I also recognise I might be barking up the wrong tree as far as ISO-8859-1 goes. I haven't worked with character sets in a similar way for years, so perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this?

Special characters that come to mind would be:

- ,
- .
- !
- `
- %

And many more.

Is there an off the shelf function to accomplish this task with PHP or any other shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually write the special characters and use function [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) :

$chars = "ÄäÖöÅå!%" ; //Add you can add also, usual latin chars are already added

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])){
    if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z{$chars}]+$/", $_GET['name'])){
        echo "Input ok, proceed") ;
       //Do stuff
    } else {
        echo "Some of characters in your input are not allowed" ;
    }
} else {
    echo "The no form submitted" ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This library seems to be doing what you are looking for:
https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify